# How to Destory the loaded Javascript file using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm Using the RequireJS to load the JavaScript files.once after loading the JavaScript how to destroy that JavaScript file

require(["abc"]function(){

}};

abc is the name of the JavaScript file loading using require js

Comment: To clarify what you're asking: you want a way to delete the file named 'abc' in its require block?

Comment: not to delete.to unload that file

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to release the content of the file "abc" because it is injected and executed in the global context.

You can only release manually each object (set to null) instancied in the file "abc" to release the memory (if they are accessible via the global context)

**UPDATE:** There is a `require.undef` method that can undefine a module :

```
require.undef('abc')
```

see more: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef